# implementing the bubble sort using linked_list. Null pointer exception

Tags: java, null-pointer

I'm trying to implement bubble sort using linked list and here is my code:

```
        itr = head;
        for (int j = 1; j < size; j++) 
        {
            for (int k = 0; k < size - 1; k++) 
            {
                if (itr.item > itr.next.item) 
                {
                    t = itr.item;
                    itr.item = itr.next.item;
                    itr.next.item = t;
                 }
                itr = itr.next;
              }
        }
```

the line

```
if (itr.item > itr.next.item)
```

gives the null pointer exception. I don't know what is wrong with my code. and size is the number of nodes in the linked list.

Comment: If you have no answer then don't vote the question down!

Comment: I think the downvotes are justified.  You show no evidence that you have attempted to debug this for yourself.  And it is a poor quality question on other grounds.

Comment: (And I'm sure that the people who down-voted knew the answer too ... but thought that the question didn't *deserve* one.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can see a couple of blunders.  But if I told you what they were, you would lose the *benefit* of learning how to debug your own code.

However, I will give you a couple of hints:

1. What is `itr.next` going to be when when you reach the end of the list?
2. What is `itr` going to be pointing after the end of the inner loop?